# I can't send message in chat, with Microsoft Graph API "Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes"

Tags: c#, azure, api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I work at a company that asked me for an API that sends messages in a private chat in Teams

After my studies, I found the Microsoft Graph API and found out how to do it,  [in this link I can do it](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
In this link I create the chat and send a message in the chat I created, from the id given to me when creating the chat

But when I do that, on my system it doesn't work

How I'm doing:

## 1-  Create the Application

> Here is my app permissions on azure
>
> [Image with permisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQQwB.png)

## 2 - I create a chat, and get the id that this call returns

This is the code i make for do this, i take the id after this

```
var user_email = IT.DsEmail;


                var chat = new Chat
                {
                    ChatType = ChatType.OneOnOne,
                    Members = new ChatMembersCollectionPage()
                {
                    new AadUserConversationMember
                    {
                        Roles = new List<String>()
                        {
                            "owner"
                        },
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                        {
                            {"user@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('notificacoes@vaxxinova.com.br')"}
                        }
                    },
                    new AadUserConversationMember
                    {
                        Roles = new List<String>()
                        {
                            "owner"
                        },
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                        {
                            {"user@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('" + user_email + "')"}
                        }
                    }
                }
                };
var user = await graphServiceClient.Chats.Request().AddAsync(chat);
```

This works! I get the id with this call, and this id I would use to send the message

**3 - Send a mesage in private chat**

Now dont work!
This is my code

```
var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
                {
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        Content = "Hello world"
                    }
                };

                
await graphServiceClient.Chats["19:35fa8078-de1a-4ec1-bb8f-85f1d4e14fa9_8848a24c-c679-415c-ac14-7f9dde86d6ec@unq.gbl.spaces"].Messages
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

When i do that, i receive this error

**Unauthorized\r\nMessage: Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.**

Can someone help me? Because in that link to test I can create the chat and send the message, but in the system I'm creating I can't?
And why in my system I can create the chat, but I can't send the message?

I create the aplication, i create the chat, but i receive a error when i tried send a mensagem

Answer (score 0):

The API that you are using with Application Permissions is only meant for importing messages as the linked document that you've shared is talking about.

Based on your scenario, it looks you want to create a bot for Teams (hence the application permissions).

If that is the case, then you should be checking the [official docs on building a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots).